# What's the word for someone who keeps everyone calm?

Tags: single-word-requests

This word would describe the person everyone goes to when they are stressed.
The person is behind the scenes, keeping everyone else functioning at their best.  Someone who never reveals what is learned in private, and is a supportive listener.  The person may never actually fix the situation, but everyone feels better for having met with her.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/keep-a-cool-head

Comment: "sane voice in the crowd" is an idiom used when people are all in a tizzy rushing off in ilconsidered  directions after some trigger.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the word 'rock' is used as a metaphor for such a person.

> Susan is always there, keeping me sane, making sure everything is on track, never losing her cool. She is my rock.

Comment: Along the same vein **pillar**

Answer (score 0):

the **peacemaker**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/peacemaker)

> a person who tries to make peace between enemies, people who are
>   quarrelling etc.

Answer (score 0):

diplomat - a diplomatic person is one who will neutralise a feud for the purpose of discussion and workings as opposed to high rate, anger, or physical action. Mediator- A mediator is such like a referee. Keeping the peace.